# Tuning hyperparameters in mlr does not produce sensible results?

Tags: r, h2o, mlr

I am trying to tune the hyperparameters in `mlr` using the `tuneParams` function. However, I can't make sense of the results it is giving me (or else Im using it incorrectly).

For example, if I create some data with a binary response and then create an `mlr` `h2o` classification model and then check the accuracy and AUC I will get some values.
Then, if I use `tuneParams` on some parameters and find a better accuracy and AUC and then plug them into my model. The resulting accuracy and AUC (for the model) does not match that found by using `tuneParams`.

Hopefully the code below will illustrate my issue:

```
library(mlr)

# Create data
set.seed(1234)
Species <- sample(c("yes", "no"), size = 150, replace = T)

dat <- data.frame(
  x1 = (Species == "yes") + rnorm(150),
  x2 = (Species == "no") + rnorm(150), Species
)

# split into training and test
train <- sample(nrow(dat), round(.7*nrow(dat))) # split 70-30
datTrain <- dat[train, ]
datTest <- dat[-train, ]

# create mlr h2o model
task <- makeClassifTask(data = dat, target = "Species")
learner <- makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type = "prob", 
                       par.vals = list(reproducible = TRUE,
                                       seed = 1))
Mod <- train(learner, task)

# Test predictions
pred <- predict(Mod, newdata = datTest)
# Evaluate performance accuracy & area under curve 
performance(pred, measures = list(acc, auc))
```

The result of the above performance check is:

```
acc       auc 
0.7111111 0.7813765
```

Now, if I tune just one of the parameters (e.g., epochs):

```
set.seed(1234)
# Tune epoch parameter
param_set <- makeParamSet(
  makeNumericParam("epochs", lower = 1, upper = 10))
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L, predict = "both") 
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 3)

res <- tuneParams(
  learner = learner, task = task, resampling = rdesc, measures = list(auc, acc),
  par.set = param_set, control = ctrl
)
```

the result I get from tuning epochs is:

```
Tune result:
Op. pars: epochs=1.95
auc.test.mean=0.8526496,acc.test.mean=0.7466667
```

Now, if I plug that value for the epochs into the learner and run the model again and check the performance:

```
set.seed(1234)
# plugging the tuned value into model and checking performance again:
learner <- makeLearner("classif.h2o.deeplearning", predict.type = "prob", 
                       par.vals = list(epochs = 1.95,
                                       reproducible = TRUE,
                                       seed = 1))
Mod <- train(learner, task)

# Test predictions
pred1 <- predict(Mod, newdata = datTest)
# Evaluate performance accuracy & area under curve 
performance(pred1, measures = list(acc, auc))
```

The resulting accuracy and AUC I get is now:

```
   acc       auc 
0.6666667 0.8036437
```

My question is, why is there such a difference between the accuracy and AUC of the results of using `tuneParams` and when I plug the tuned values into the learner?
Or am I using or interpreting `tuneParams` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting different results because you're evaluating the learner using different train and test data. If I use the same 3-fold CV, I get the same results:

```
set.seed(1234)
resample(learner, task, cv3, list(auc, acc))

Aggr perf: auc.test.mean=0.8526496,acc.test.mean=0.7466667
```

In general, every computed performance is only an *estimate* of the true generalization performance. This will vary depending on what method of resampling you choose and what data.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. But the performance results obtained from using the resample function with the same 3-fold CV, is the actual performance of my fitted model with the tuned parameters?

Comment: It is a performance *estimate* -- what, based on the resampling and data you've given, appears to be the performance. The *actual* performance can and will be different (as you've seen) when different data/resamplings are used. One way to get a more robust performance estimate is to increase the number of folds (10 fold is quite standard) and, for tuning, use nested resampling -- https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/nested_resampling.html

Comment: Then, when training the model, how do I use the same data/resamplings that are used during the tuning process?

Comment: You usually don't. You would take the data and resampling for your actual task. The performance of a model trained with the hyperparameters from the tuning process is estimated by the the result of the tuning process. It is however only an estimate and therefore the performance you observe may be different.